# How does the Spark M7 “Concurrent Fine-grain Memory Migration” benefit a garbage collector?

Tags: memory-management, memory-hardware, garbage-collection, cpu

Sun has been making a lot of noise about the Spark M7 and its inbuilt support for the java garbage collector.   However there seem to be very little easy to find information about it.   Please can someone explain what is so great about “Concurrent Fine-grain Memory Migration”?

Does the M7 cpu have any other novel ways of helping a garbage collector?

Comment: Could you provide some material about the Spark M7 so that we can link the commercial product (which computer scientists don't always know well) with the underlying design principles?

Comment: @Gilles, the best I have found is http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/servers/sparc-enterprise/migration/m7-next-gen-sparc-presentation-2326292.html    somewhat lacking any any useful detail.

Comment: It does however remind me a bit of what the c4 garbage collector does as part of its  read barrier.